# Converting between time formats syntax

Tags: php, date, datetime

just having a little trouble converting between php time formats... not sure where I am off. Amongst other things, I am changing between 12 and 24 hour time.

```
$start_time= "02/12/2015 12:00 AM";  //this is a string

$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i a', $start_time);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i');

echo ($newDateString);  //empty at the moment
```

My desired output format is:

```
2015-02-12 12:00
```

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why 2-12 should become 2-2 ?

Comment: `02/12/2015` -> `2015-02-02` How ?

Comment: Try to do this `$myDateTime = new DateTime($start_time);` instead of this `$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i a', $start_time);` or use `$myDateTime = strtotime($start_time);` to parse the time.

Comment: @rizer123 typo. apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code except a missing `;` in the first line. Only one small change you can make. In the output you can change `H` to `h` since your desired output is in 12 hour format, rest is already fine.

```
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d h:i');
```

> 2015-02-12 12:00

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/278397)**

P.S: Sometimes i seriously wonder some up-votes were not necessary at all, I mean you could have run this code yourself and noticed it was already good. Just gave some up-votes to someone without taking any real help from them.

My Act of telling you that you are missing a `;` and need to change one letter is not a real help. Waste of time for you too :)